# Webpage's HTML using Phantom

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS to load a page (that uses Javascript to load items on the webpage) and returns all the HTML on the page (at least within the `<body />` tags) to the PHP function that executes `phantomjs httpget.js`.

**Problem:** I can get phantomjs to return the `document.title`, but asking it to `console.log(document.body)` simple gives me a `[object Object]`. How can I extract the page's HTML?

*It also takes much longer to load the webpage using phantomjs compared to the browser*.

**httpget.js**

```
console.log('hello!');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("http://www.asos.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616#parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=900&sort=1",
    function(status){
        console.log('Page title is ' + page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.body;
        }));
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

**Output** *(running from shell)*

```
hello!
Page title is [object Object]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.body.innerHTML` contains the HTML of the body.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with node.js or this library. Note that document.body.innerHTML doesn't inclue the <body> or </body> tags.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what this has to do with Node.js as you appear to be using PhantomJS directly, not node (or phantom via node-phantom)...

But to answer your question, you need to do this:

```
var html = page.evaluate(function () {
    var root = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
    var html = root ? root.outerHTML : document.body.innerHTML;
    return html
});
```

This works with pages that don't have an outer <html> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation, `page.content` gets you the entire HTML.